# C# - EF Code First Layers Definition and Logic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, layer

I'm creating an layered app in C# and trying to use EF 6 in it.
I want the code first approach (POCO).
My idea of layers (projects):

- DAL (Entity Framework 6).
- Entities (Where I have my classes that represent my tables in the DB, or entities representing my DB objects).
- Business (I add via method extension methods to the Entites classes, like 'void CalculateTaxes()' to a Product class).
- Presentation (UI, for now is Win Forms, later can be web...)

First, I'm relatively new to all of it and I'm studying layer architectures.

**The question**: The DAL layer gotta reference the Entities layer (where I have my DB objects) for creating and maintaning the DB and the Entities layer gotta reference the DAL layer to access the objects from the DB, and I cannot do this (circular dependency).
How should I procede in this scenario? For more experencied developers, is this the best approach?

Comment: explain it please "the Entities layer gotta see the DAL layer to access the objects from the DB", entities are objects from DB.

Comment: EF will remove the need for you to have a particular DAL, just create POCOS in your Entities layer then create a DbContext

Comment: I edited my post. From a MSDN post from MVP Renato Haddad, he created a DAL project and a Entities project, representing the DB objects. In my scenario the DAL has to reference de Entities project and vice-versa.

Comment: of course, you could go with repositories, that might make sense in a DAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Entities layer gotta see the DAL layer to access the objects from the DB

This is where you should break your dependency.  The entities should be storage-agnostic.  The current popular method of bridging the entities and EF is a Repository layer that encapsulates the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) logic.

Comment: That's right, actually, the example from MSDN where a DAL class was created was for a repository example. Thanks!